# Can my query be enhanced in terms of speed using athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am using `athena` to query the data that I am looking for.

Below is my query.

```
SELECT
split_part(KEY,'/',1) as serviceid, 
split_part(KEY,'/',2) as eventtype,
cast(date_parse(concat(split_part(KEY,'/',3), '-' , split_part(KEY,'/',4), '-', split_part(KEY,'/',5)),'%Y-%m-%d') as date) as createTime
FROM TEST2
WHERE dt = '2023-05-24-01-00' and cardinality(split(KEY,'/')) > 5;
```

As you can see, I use the `split_part` many times to extract the field.
I think that it is a little bit repeated procedures so that I could reduce the `split_part` for its speed.

Since the key field consists of strings delimited by `/`, I use the split many times.

Can it be achieved?

Any help will very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `split` is a very efficient function and you call it only a handful of times. It is unlikely to be your performance bottleneck. Probably, the performance of your query has to do with the data it's querying. Also, even trivial Athena queries can take 10+ seconds - Athena is not a low-latency system by design.

Comment: `and cardinality(split(KEY,'/')) > 5` is "non-sargable" and probably causes a table scan, so unless you can drop this filter or re-arrange the data so you no longer need split - there is not a lot you can do

Comment: I would probably also recommend to analyze how is your data stored. You might get better performance by choosing the right file format/size/compression algorithm and distribution (partitioning/bucketing, etc).

Comment: Can you please describe how you structure the files on S3? E.g., `s3://bucket_name/table_name/my_date=yyyy-mm-dd/files.parquet`